# Developing Grails plugins on GitHub

Tags: github, grails-plugin

I was wondering if anything changed since the last time I checked (over a year ago) in regard to developing Grails plugins using GitHub instead of https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins.

The last time I checked it was required to use the git-svn approach and to effectively have 2 repositories - one on github and another one in https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins.

Has there been any improvement to this process?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to maintain the plugin's code in an external repo, just use the `zipOnly` flag when running `release-plugin`. This will just check in the plugin zip and plugin.xml files to the Grails plugin SVN repo but ignore your code. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/release-plugin.html for the `release-plugin` options.

As an example look at http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/ and see http://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core for the plugin code.